# How can I plot 2d FEM results using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, mesh

I'm developing a 2D plane finite element tool. One of the features is the ability to visualize the stresses on a particular object.

This tool creates a quadrilateral mesh using the following data:

- **nodes**: numpy array `[[x1 y1], [x2 y2], etc]` -> `x` and `y` coordinates of every node in the mesh
- **elements**: numpy array `[[1 2 3 4], [2 3 5 6]]` -> every line of the array corresponds to the 4 points of one particular element of the mesh.

I was able to implement a method that plots the mesh:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import numpy as np


def showMeshPlot(nodes, elements):

    y = nodes[:,0]
    z = nodes[:,1]

    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640311/matplotlib-unstructered-quadrilaterals-instead-of-triangles
    def quatplot(y,z, quatrangles, ax=None, **kwargs):

        if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
        yz = np.c_[y,z]
        verts= yz[quatrangles]
        pc = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection(verts, **kwargs)
        ax.add_collection(pc)
        ax.autoscale()

    plt.figure()
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

    quatplot(y,z, np.asarray(elements), ax=None, color="crimson", facecolor="None")
    if nodes:            
        plt.plot(y,z, marker="o", ls="", color="crimson")

    plt.title('This is the plot for: quad')
    plt.xlabel('Y Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Z Axis')


    plt.show()

nodes = np.array([[0,0], [0,0.5],[0,1],[0.5,0], [0.5,0.5], [0.5,1], [1,0], 
                  [1,0.5],[1,1]])
elements = np.array([[0,3,4,1],[1,4,5,2],[3,6,7,4],[4,7,8,5]])
stresses = np.array([1,2,3,4])

showMeshPlot(nodes, elements)
```

Which produces a plot like this:

[image: quad mesh]

Now, i have an 1D array with the stresses on the object, with the same length as the elements array.

My question is how can i visualize those stresses (with a scalar bar) using matplotlib? I looked into pcolormesh, but i couldn't understand how it could work with my data. Here's an example of what i want to achieve (credits to robbievanleeuwen):

[image: example]

Note: I couldn't replicate the above example because he uses a triangular mesh instead of quads.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `stress` in the code and the code is in general not runnable, which makes it hard to give an answer here. The broad idea here is of course to supply a colormap, a norm and an array to the PolyCollection and create a colorbar for that PolyCollection.

Comment: That was just an example of the method i have to create a regular wireframe mesh. I just want to give colour to the elements via a stress array (1D with the same length as the elements array). Basically, i want to find a way to associate my elements array (with the format shown in the question) to the stress array.

Comment: I don't currently see any reason why my suggestion above would not work. But if you want that as an answer I would want to make sure that it does. I can only do that with a runnable code provided in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i changed the example so it's workable now. Basically i want, for example, stresses[0] to be related to elements[0] and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PolyCollection is a `ScalarMappable`. It can have an array of values, a colormap and a normalization set. Here you would supply the `stresses` array to the PolyCollection and choose some colormap to use. 
The rest is rearanging the function a bit, such that can take the additional data as input and creates a colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import numpy as np


def showMeshPlot(nodes, elements, values):

    y = nodes[:,0]
    z = nodes[:,1]

    def quatplot(y,z, quatrangles, values, ax=None, **kwargs):

        if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
        yz = np.c_[y,z]
        verts= yz[quatrangles]
        pc = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection(verts, **kwargs)
        pc.set_array(values)
        ax.add_collection(pc)
        ax.autoscale()
        return pc

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    pc = quatplot(y,z, np.asarray(elements), values, ax=ax, 
             edgecolor="crimson", cmap="rainbow")
    fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax)        
    ax.plot(y,z, marker="o", ls="", color="crimson")

    ax.set(title='This is the plot for: quad', xlabel='Y Axis', ylabel='Z Axis')

    plt.show()

nodes = np.array([[0,0], [0,0.5],[0,1],[0.5,0], [0.5,0.5], [0.5,1], [1,0], 
                  [1,0.5],[1,1]])
elements = np.array([[0,3,4,1],[1,4,5,2],[3,6,7,4],[4,7,8,5]])
stresses = np.array([1,2,3,4])

showMeshPlot(nodes, elements, stresses)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have a smooth transition between the quads somehow?

Comment: This would counteract the initial idea of plotting quads. You may use the `tricontour` from the other answer to get smoothed shapes.

Answer (score 10):

After thinking for a while, the following code is one of the easiest ways of plotting a FEM mesh (with a nodal scalar field) using `matplotlib`.

This solution is based on `matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf()`. Unfortunately, `matplotlib` does not have an easy way to plot filled contours if you have quadrangles or higher order elements in your finite element mesh. In order to plot the contours, all elements must first be "cut" into triangles, for example, a quadrangle can be split or cut into 2 triangles, and so on...

A custom method for plotting the mesh lines must also be employed, since `matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf()` only works with a triangular grid/mesh. For this, `matplotlib.pyplot.fill()` was used.

Here is the full code with a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

# converts quad elements into tri elements
def quads_to_tris(quads):
    tris = [[None for j in range(3)] for i in range(2*len(quads))]
    for i in range(len(quads)):
        j = 2*i
        n0 = quads[i][0]
        n1 = quads[i][1]
        n2 = quads[i][2]
        n3 = quads[i][3]
        tris[j][0] = n0
        tris[j][1] = n1
        tris[j][2] = n2
        tris[j + 1][0] = n2
        tris[j + 1][1] = n3
        tris[j + 1][2] = n0
    return tris

# plots a finite element mesh
def plot_fem_mesh(nodes_x, nodes_y, elements):
    for element in elements:
        x = [nodes_x[element[i]] for i in range(len(element))]
        y = [nodes_y[element[i]] for i in range(len(element))]
        plt.fill(x, y, edgecolor='black', fill=False)

# FEM data
nodes_x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
nodes_y = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
nodal_values = [1.0, 0.9, 1.1, 0.9, 2.1, 2.1, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8]
elements_tris = [[2, 6, 5], [5, 6, 10], [10, 9, 5]]
elements_quads = [[0, 1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 5, 4], [3, 4, 8, 7], [4, 5, 9, 8]]
elements = elements_tris + elements_quads

# convert all elements into triangles
elements_all_tris = elements_tris + quads_to_tris(elements_quads)

# create an unstructured triangular grid instance
triangulation = tri.Triangulation(nodes_x, nodes_y, elements_all_tris)

# plot the finite element mesh
plot_fem_mesh(nodes_x, nodes_y, elements)

# plot the contours
plt.tricontourf(triangulation, nodal_values)

# show
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Just by changing the FEM data (nodes, nodal values, elements) the above code can be used for more complicated meshes, however, the code is only prepared to deal with meshes containing triangles and quadrangles:

[image]

You may notice that for large meshes, `matplotlib` will get slow. Also with `matplotlib` 
you can't visualize 3D-elements. So for better efficiency and more functionality, consider using instead VTK, for example.

Comment: [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) is a nice module for using VTK in Python.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option is to use [tricontour](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html). You already have the triangulation, right?

It creates plots like this one:
[image]

([from here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_smooth_user.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-tricontour-smooth-user-py))

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontour.html

Comment: The problem is that i don't have a triangulation per se. I have elements with 4 nodes, and i think that `tricontour` only works for triangles..

Comment: Split the quads? ;)

Comment: Also, you don't need the triangulation. If you just pass x,y the function will create it using Delaunay. `tricontour(x, y, ...)` Then you are not plotting the mesh you calculated on, but who cares if it is colored plot. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! but i didn't understand very well what you mean.. Can you make an example with the updated code i posted in my question? Basically i want, for example, stresses[0] to be related to elements[0] and so on

Comment: In principle you are right, that you may pass the points directly to `tricontour`. This would work in the general case; however here you'd have two issues: First, the number of stress values does not match the number of triangles which are produced and it would be really difficult to get a mapping from those created triangles to the colors. Second, it will fail if the mesh contains "holes" like in the example picture, because the triangulation would simply produce triangles within the holes as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then he needs to store the triangles, he needs them for the FEM anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[pyvista](https://docs.pyvista.org/getting-started/what-is-a-mesh.html) is a easier way to plot fem mesh instead of using matplotlib. Your can use arbitary vtk mesh which i can reproduce with [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio). One get easy 2D and 3D visualization with attributes on nodes for displacment or on whole elements for stress or strain.