# Most efficient way to plot finite element mesh using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numeric

My question is fairly simple but  for those who need more context see the [wikipedia page on finite element methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method#Choosing_a_basis).

I am looking for the most efficient way to plot a mesh using matplotlib given the following information, coordinates of each node, what nodes belong to each element, and the value each node has. Below I have some example data and image showing what the mesh looks like

```
nodeinfo=[[0.000,0.000],[1.000,0.000],[2.000,0.500],[0.000,1.000],
[1.000,1.000],[1.750,1.300],[1.000,1.700]]
elementInfo=[[1,2,5],[5,4,1],[2,3,6],[6,5,2],[4,5,7],[5,6,7]]
nodevalues=[1,2,1,2,7,4,5]
```

[image]

nodeinfo is the coordinates of each nodes(e.g. node 7 has coordinates (1,1.7)), elementInfo gives what nodes each element is composed of (e.g. element 3 has nodes 2,3,6), nodevalues gives the value of each node(e.g. node 5 has value 7).

> Using this info how can I plot meshes with matplotlib with a colour gradient showing the different values of the nodes(if possible it would be great if there was a colour gradient between nodes as each element is linear).

**Note**
If you want to use it have created a bit of code that organizes the information into node objects.

```
class node:
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, number, xCord, yCord):
        self.number=number
        self.value=1
        self.isOnBoundary=False
        self.xCord=xCord
        self.yCord=yCord
        self.boundaryType=None
        self.element=[]

    #makes all class variables callable
    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def checkIfOnBoundary(self,boundarylist):
        # Checks if the node is on the boundary when it is invoked
        # If the node is not on the boundary then it is set to false

        if self.number in boundarylist:
            self.isOnBoundary=True
            self.boundaryType=boundarylist[self.number][0]
            if self.boundaryType == "Dirchlet":
                self.value=boundarylist[self.number][1]
        else:
            self.isOnBoundary=False

    def setElement(self,elementInfo):
        #given a list in the form [element1,element2,...,elementn]
        #where element1 is a list that contains all the nodes that are on that element
        for element in elementInfo:
            if self.number in element:
                self.element.append(elementInfo.index(element)+1)


    def setValue(self,value):
        # changes the value of the node
        self.value=value

    def description(self):
        return "Node Number: {}, Node Value: {}, Element Node Belongs to: {}, Is Node On the Boundary: {}".format(self.number, self.value, self.element, self.isOnBoundary)

nodeinfo=[[0.000,0.000],[1.000,0.000],[2.000,0.500],[0.000,1.000],
[1.000,1.000],[1.750,1.300],[1.000,1.700]]
elementInfo=[[1,2,5],[5,4,1],[2,3,6],[6,5,2],[4,5,7],[5,6,7]]
nodevalues=[1,2,1,2,7,4,5]

#create list of node objects which we will call on often
nodes=[]
for i in range(len(nodeinfo)):
    print(i)
    nodes.append(node(i+1,nodeinfo[i][0],nodeinfo[i][1]))
    nodes[i].setElement(elementInfo)

#print information related to each object
for phi in nodes:
    print(vars(phi))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)` to create an unstructured triangular grid, where:

- `x` is a 1D list containing the x-coordinate of each node;
- `y` is a 1D list containing the y-coordinate of each node;
- `triangles` is a "2D list" containing the nodes of each triangle (0
  based index);

Second, use `matplotlib.pyplot.triplot(triangulation, linespec)` to plot just the mesh (lines only), where:

- `triangulation` is the instance created by `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)`;
- `linespec` is the line specification;

Third, use `matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf(triangulation, scalars)` to plot the scalar field contours , where:

- `triangulation` is the instance created by `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)`;
- `scalars` a 1D list containing the nodal scalar data;

Finally, use `matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar()` and `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`.

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

nodes_x = [0.000, 1.000, 2.000, 0.000, 1.000, 1.750, 1.000]
nodes_y = [0.000, 0.000, 0.500, 1.000, 1.000, 1.300, 1.700]
scalars = [1.000, 2.000, 1.000, 2.000, 7.000, 4.000, 5.000]
elements = [
    [0, 1, 4],
    [4, 3, 0],
    [1, 2, 5],
    [5, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, 6],
    [4, 5, 6]
    ]

triangulation = tri.Triangulation(nodes_x, nodes_y, elements)
plt.triplot(triangulation, '-k')
plt.tricontourf(triangulation, scalars)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to visualize other types of 2D-elements (quadrangles or higher-order elements), you must first "split" these into triangles. However, if you want to visualize 3D-elements, or if you want to make your life easier and your code more efficient/faster for large meshes, you must abandon matplotlib and use something like VTK.

**EDIT**

Check my answer on the following question to plot FEM meshes that contain quadrangles:

[How can I plot 2d FEM results using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202014/how-can-i-plot-2d-fem-results-using-matplotlib/59971611#59971611)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor.html) if your mesh is discretized with triangular elements: [Demo from matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK2KY.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35282318)