# getting ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2, when it is Nx2?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh

I am trying to plot a mesh using node coordinates and connectivity as outlined here:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202014/how-can-i-plot-2d-fem-results-using-matplotlib)

I have a list of node coordinates stored in a numpy array (x y and z coordinates)

I define x and y as:

```
x = coords[:,0]
y = coords[:,1]
```

I have the node connectivity in a numpy array `connectivity`, it has the id numbers of the coordinates that connect together

then, following their example, do the following:

```
xy = np.c_[x,y]
verts= xy[connectivity]
pc = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection(verts)
```

and I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\deden\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dhi\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 130, in __init__
    "'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2")

ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2
```

to check:

`xy.shape[1]` is 2 and 
`xy.ndim` is 2

the line 130 in the file in the traceback is:

```
vertices = _to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)
if vertices.ndim != 2 or vertices.shape[1] != 2:
    raise ValueError(
        "'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2")
```

and `_to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)` calls:

```
def _to_unmasked_float_array(x):
    """
    Convert a sequence to a float array; if input was a masked array, masked
    values are converted to nans.
    """
    if hasattr(x, 'mask'):
        return np.ma.asarray(x, float).filled(np.nan)
    else:
        return np.asarray(x, float)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error msg if `verts.shape[1]` and `verts.ndim` = 2

also `np.asarray(verts, float).shape[1]` and `np.asarray(verts, float).ndim` is also 2

what the heck is going on? am I missing something? would really appreciate anyones help

also..

```
verts.shape
```

returns

```
(181660, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to draw a collection, you want `verts` to be a list of vertices *per polygon*. More technically spoken, as [the documentation puts it](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection),

> `verts` is a sequence of `( verts0, verts1, ...)` where `verts_i` is a sequence of xy tuples of vertices, or an equivalent numpy array of shape (nv, 2).

Hence, if your collection only has a single polygon, it still needs to be a list with a single entry. In your case

```
PolyCollection([verts])
```

Comment: thank you, this approach worked - I have an array of number of nodes per mesh element, so basically just split up my coords based on those counts, so my verts object was then a list of arrays where each array was Nx2 with the vertices for each polygon/element....then just doing `PolyCollection(verts)` worked.

Comment: do you happen to know how I can color the faces of these polys by another array? I got the average z value for each polygon (based on the z values of the pertinent nodes) and tried adding `cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet` into the `PolyCollection` call, then doing `pc.set_array(zs)` (zs is a np.array with length of my verts list) but when I try to plot it I get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`...if you have any ideas let me know I can edit the OP to have the full traceback

Comment: Sounds like a different problem. So you can ask a new question with a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: thanks for the help on the OP, I ended up figuring the next issue out