# What is the equivalent of "patch" function in MATLAB in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 2D FEM mesh in Python using Matlab code. I have my X,Y and color value arrays. Each of these arrays are in the shape of (Nodes per Element x Number of Total Elements). I tried to use pcolormesh but it doesn't produce the same result as patch function in Matlab.

What my plot looks like with the code `axstress_xx.pcolormesh(X,Y,stress_xx,cmap='jet')` in Python:

[image]

What it actually should look like with the code `patch(app.postProcessGraph,X,Y,stress_xx,'FaceColor','interp','LineStyle',app.enableLine)` in Matlab:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom left part of the plot doesn't seem to be right and also the plot seems not to have the right colors. I checked X,Y and color values both in Matlab and Python and they're totally the same. What am I missing here? Is pcolormesh different from patch function in terms of plotting mechanism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot 2d FEM results using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202014/how-can-i-plot-2d-fem-results-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Did you try `pcolormesh(...., shading='gouraud')`?

Comment: By the way ["How Bad Is Your Colormap?"](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) explains why 'jet' isn't an ideal choice for this application.