# How To Assign Color Values To Vertices Instead of Face Colors in Matplotlib When Plotting a Polygon?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data regarding x, y and color values which are all NxM arrays. Normally, when using Polygon function from Matplotlib, it needs to have color values per FACE (which would be a 1xM array) instead of VERTEX. However, my color data is per VERTEX. So, my question is that is there a way to convert my vertex data to single face color data? Or even better, is there a way to plot polygons using color values per vertex instead of per face?

Note: What I want is quite similar to MATLAB's patch function which you can use color values per vertex.

Edit:
Below, you can find a data example of one element. A mesh consists of many elements and below is just one of them. X and Y refer to coordinates and C refers to color values of each coordinate. Note that the below arrays are actually stored as columns in the original code as there are many other elements.

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([0,0.176611,0.343377,0.366506,0.390424,0.254526,0.117785,0.602218])
Y = np.array([0,0.0248673,0.0436277,0.0834644,0.123043,0.110448,0.0995953,0.0509885])
C = np.array([0.136649,0.114582,0.100576,0.102412,0.102754,0.104971,0.110123,0.120756])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign colors to vertices instead of faces, `pcolormesh` accepts the parameter `shading='gouraud'`. Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 8)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 3))
cmap = 'plasma'
axs[0].scatter(X, Y, s=50, c=Z, cmap=cmap, edgecolors='black')
axs[0].set_title('given vertex colors')
axs[1].pcolormesh(x, y, Z, shading='gouraud', cmap=cmap)
axs[1].scatter(X, Y, s=50, c=Z, cmap=cmap, edgecolors='black')
axs[1].set_title('interpolated vertex colors')
axs[1].set_xlim(axs[0].get_xlim())
axs[1].set_ylim(axs[0].get_ylim())
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: While this solution helped me in some aspects, I still need a little more help with my own case. The points that I'm going to interpolate don't form a rectangle like this. In my case, areas are divided to elements like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524882/what-is-the-equivalent-of-patch-function-in-matlab-in-python

These elements also could be triangles so I think I need a solution that doesn't involve vectors.

Comment: Matplotlib as [`tripcolor(...., shading='gouraud')`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tripcolor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tripcolor) to do the same for irregular triangular meshes (quad meshes can easily be transformed to triangular ones).  Make sure the `c=colors` has the same number of elements as there are points. If you provide some toy data, it would be easier to show how it fits with your workflow.

Comment: I shared a sample data of one element (i.e. one of the rectangles from the post I shared above). There may also be other data types which there are 3, 4 or 6 coordinates depending on the element type. In our case, there are 8 coordinates where 4 of them are on the edges and the other 4 are on the corners.

Comment: With your example, you can call `plt.tricontourf(X, Y, C, levels=256)` (default uses the 'viridis' colormap).  `tricontourf` interpolates between points (there is no concept of input polygons; internally it connects the points with triangles; you can force holes by adding points with `np.nan` as color value)

Comment: This works great with my case, thank you. Is there a way to add shading using tricontourf though? The whole point of having different types of element is to see the interpolation between vertices just like in pcolormesh's gouraud shading.

Comment: Setting `levels=256` has the same effect as gouraud shading.  You can choose a colormap with less different colors (default is 'viridis', maybe choose `cmap='inferno'`, for others see [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html))